# How to get sector numbers of a file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, android

We are developing Android application (Android UI and C application through JNI) and File system is ext4.

Is there any Linux system call or Android API to find out sector numbers allocated for a file.

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [FIBMAP](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2009/06/fibmap-ioctl-file-system-block-number.html) or [FIEMAP](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-fiemap-ioctl-to-get-file-extents.html) ioctls to read file blocks or file extents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My application doesn't have root permission, hence i am unable to use ioctls. Please let me know any other way to read block number.

Comment: ok. we will try this from Android-C application and update on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can get the file blocks and more information using stat command.

> stat [OPTIONS]... FILE ...

For example you could know the info about my.cnf like this:

> stat /etc/my.cnf

You can use the options to get different format sequences for files using the --help option alone.

Comment: We can't use stat command from Android application having C module. So I was referring stat function, but it doesn't give block numbers detail. It is giving number of blocks allocated for a file and block size.  kindly clarify this.

Comment: Either stat(2) or statx(2) can't report the information about sector number.